# Issues installing bitwig 4.2.3 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, sound, software-installation, production

Currently trying to install bitwig 4.2.3 on ubuntu 18.04 and I am receiving this error:

```
(base) cocopalacelove@system76-pc:~/bitwig$ sudo apt install ./bitwig-studio-4.2.3.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'bitwig-studio' instead of './bitwig-studio-4.2.3.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bitwig-studio : Depends: zlib1g:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxau6:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxdmcp6:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-icccm4:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-util1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-shm0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-xinput0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxkbcommon0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpixman-1-0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcairo2:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? Add the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

The output suggest that you need `i386` architecture.
Try to install it before issuing your command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I would also check your version of bitwig. I find it strange it would need `ì386`.